# Polymer-Project objects not rendering in OS X 10.10

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, polymer, osx-yosemite

Recently I have been considering using Polymer elements in a project I am working on. However, I am unable to see any elements being rendered in the new beta version of safari for OS X 10.10 Yosemite. I completely understand that Yosemite and Safari are currently in the DP phase, but I am curious as to why the new verison of Safari has broken compatibility with Polymer elements (I can confirm Polymer elements work in Mavericks version of Safari).

I was able to open the developer console and spot an error. I am unable to reach the exact error at this time, but I know the error was at patches-mdv.js at line 57, claiming a Read Only error.

I just tested the Polymer Project website on my iPhone with iOS8, having the same results.

Does anyone have an idea on what I could do to fix this issue temporarily until the Polymer-Project team fixes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One apparent problem is that the Safari beta has at least one low-level property accessor (specifially `HTMLBaseElement.prototype.href`) that is misconfigured from the standard.

So, cursory investigation implies this is a bug in Safari, not Polymer.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Did not mean to imply the Polymer team was the reason for the fault, I assumed it was the Apple side.

Comment: Oh, no worries, I was just trying to be clear; when these super low-level problems crop-up, we sometimes can't work around them.